# record shows up on query result even if not supposed to

Tags: mysql

I need to query some tables on my database and to do so i must use some nested queries. Here's the one that didn't work well:

```
SELECT * 
FROM inserzioni
WHERE inserzioni.idComune
IN (

    SELECT tcomuni.IDCOMUNE
    FROM tcomuni, tprovince
    WHERE tcomuni.IDPROVINCIA
    IN (

        SELECT tprovince.IDPROVINCIA
        FROM tprovince
        WHERE tprovince.IDREGIONE =  '20'
    )
)
AND inserzioni.idProdAcq
IN (

    SELECT prodacq.idPa
    FROM prodacq
    WHERE DATEDIFF( NOW( ) , prodacq.dataInizio ) < prodacq.durata
    AND prodacq.f_attivo =1
)
GROUP BY inserzioni.idInserzione
```

The problem shows up in the last nest. In the result table i see one record that is not supposed to be there since the idProdAcq of this record is no longer in the prodacq table. Is there anything i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your posted query can be simplified to below using `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT i.* 
FROM inserzioni i
JOIN tcomuni t ON i.idComune = t.IDCOMUNE
JOIN tprovince tp ON t.IDPROVINCIA = tp.IDPROVINCIA
AND tp.IDREGIONE = '20'
JOIN prodacq p ON i.idProdAcq = p.idPa
AND DATEDIFF( NOW( ) , p.dataInizio ) < p.durata
    AND p.f_attivo =1
GROUP BY i.idInserzione;
```

Comment: @Jannuzzo, you said `idProdAcq of this record is no longer in the prodacq table` ... are you sure? Cause you are doing a `INNER JOIN` here which will get only matching records. Check and make sure again once.

Comment: i just control it because it was unexpected to find it. this record has idProdAcq 3771 and when i look into the prodacq table i have record with id 3770 and then 3772.